# Error when I press Sign Up on SwiftUI app

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swiftui

I have this app that's basically just a login/signup page linked to firebase. However, whenever I press signup/login I get the following error.

> 020-01-15 22:48:22.240265-0500 CampusMovesLogin[5711:1386347] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The link provided is not valid for email/link sign-in. Please check the link by calling isSignInWithEmailLink:link: on Auth before attempting to use it for email/link sign-in.'

Debugging leads to find that the error is caused by the following function which calls another function in a different file.

```
func signIn(){
    session.signIn(email: email, password: password) {
        (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            self.error = error.localizedDescription
        } else {
            self.email = ""
            self.password = ""
        }
    }
}
```

The previous calls the next block of code.

```
func signIn(email: String, password: String, handler: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback){
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, link: password, completion: handler)
}
```

If anyone knows what this is, please help.

Comment: What I know what type of `session` object is?

Comment: It seems the wrong signIn method is called. If you are going to sign in with **email** & **password**, use the `signIn(withEmail:password:completion:)` method instead of the `link` version used here.

Comment: Or if you need the link based authentication, follow [Authenticate with Firebase Using Email Link in iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/email-link-auth)

Comment: Spot on answers right there, @nayem! :-)  If you post these as an answer, OP can accept it, and the system will know that this question has been sufficiently answered.